# Javascript code only working after page refresh and not first viewing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

i am using a bit of javascript that checks all of my images for their width and adds a class depending.

It looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// check each image in the .blogtest divs for their width. If its less than X make it full size, if not its poor and keep it normal
var box = $(".blogtest");
box.find("img.buildimage").each(function() {
   var img = $(this), width = img.width();
   if (width >= 700) {
      img.addClass("buildimage-large");
   } else if (width < 700) {
      img.addClass("buildimage-small");
   }
}); 
});
```

The issue is, the images dont have a class added to them when you first visit the page, instead they only work when you refresh the page.

Any fix for this?

Comment: @zer02 media queries aren't going to help with image widths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the load handler because when the ready handler is triggered the image might not be loaded so the width will be 0 first time, in the second time the image might be cached in the browser making to be loaded faster so when the ready handler is triggered the image might be already loaded so it is working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // check each image in the .blogtest divs for their width. If its less than X make it full size, if not its poor and keep it normal
    var box = $(".blogtest");
    box.find("img.buildimage").on('load', function () {
        var img = $(this),
            width = img.width();
        if (width >= 700) {
            img.addClass("buildimage-large");
        } else if (width < 700) {
            img.addClass("buildimage-small");
        }
    }).filter(function () {
        //if the image is already loaded manually trigger the event
        return this.complete;
    }).trigger('load');
});
```

But an additional point to be kept in mind is, by the time the ready handler is triggered if the image is already loaded then the registered `load` handler will not get triggered so after registering the event handler we need to filter out the images which are already loaded and then manually trigger the load event so that for those images the load event will get triggered

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.ready` handler does not wait for external things like stylesheets or images to load:

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.

A load event handler in jQuery looks something like this:

```
$(document).on('load', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

The reason it worked on page refresh was probably due to the browser caching the images (and thus they're ready before the browser has finished parsing the HTML.